# Conditional and static classes with Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am pretty new with Angular and I tried to add conditional class for other classes. E.g

```
<div ng-class="{'text': true, 'text-with-decoration': summerEdition}">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

This work as I expect - "text-with-decoration" is set only when `summerEdition` is truthy. But my question is about other classes which are static. In this case I have only one class "text" and I have set `true` for them. But what should I do when I have e.g 10 static classes or more ? Should I be repetitive and for each create something like above ? `'class1": true, 'class2': true ... forever`.

Comment: I think you can mix them, `<div class="text" ng-class="...">...`

Comment: Seems to work, thanks :)